# ¿Cómo agregar un marcador de google maps en un MapFragment? Xamarin Android

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.android, supportmapfragment

Tengo un Fragment, en donde utilizo la Api de google para mostrar un mapa, pero no puedo agregar marcadores, me podrían ayudar por favor, ésto es lo que intenté y no pude

```
class Point {
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public string Marker { get; set; }
    }
    internal class DetailMapFragment : BaseFragment , IOnMapReadyCallback
    {
        public override int LayoutId => Resource.Layout.map_page;
        private GoogleMap GoogleMap;
        private SupportMapFragment _mapFragment;
        protected override void InitViews()
        {
            try
            {
                Point point = new Point();
                point.Latitude = -12.04212;
                point.Longitude = -77.1053528;
                point.Marker = "Perú";
                _mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) Activity.SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map);

                if (_mapFragment == null)
                {
                    GoogleMapOptions mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions()
                                             .InvokeMapType(GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal)
                                             .InvokeZoomControlsEnabled(false)
                                             .InvokeMaxZoomPreference(20)
                                             .InvokeCompassEnabled(true);

                    FragmentTransaction fragTx = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                    _mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.NewInstance(mapOptions);
                    fragTx.Add(Resource.Id.map, _mapFragment, "map");
                    fragTx.Commit();

                    GoogleMap.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions().SetPosition(new LatLng(point.Latitude, point.Longitude)).SetTitle(point.Marker));


                }
                _mapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
        public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            this.GoogleMap = googleMap;
        }
        void IOnMapReadyCallback.OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            try
            {
                this.GoogleMap = googleMap;
                if (googleMap != null)
                {
                    googleMap.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLng(new LatLng(-11.083271, -76.207374)));
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_small"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Retroexcavadora"
      android:textColor="@color/black_text"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lblLocation"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/lblLocation"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_small"
      android:text="Odebreth | Lima, Perú"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lblDate"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblTitle"
        />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/lblDate"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:text="23 Mar 2018"
      android:textColor="@color/black_text"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lblDetail"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblLocation"
        />

  <View
      android:id="@+id/divider"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:background="@color/gray_text"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lblDetail"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/lblDetail"
        />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/lblDetail"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Detalles"
      android:textAllCaps="true"
      android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/mapView"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/mapView"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblDate"
        />   

       <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblDetail"/>   />

  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/detailLayout"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="120dp"
      android:background="@color/black_text"
      android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_small"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Inverse"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mapView">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblSalary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Salario"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lblSalary"
        android:text="$26,000.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_send"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Enviar CV"/>

  </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Con este código puedes incluso agregar un icono personalizado, saludos.

```
Gmap.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .SetPosition(new LatLng(item.Object.Latitude, item.Object.Longitude))
                                    .SetTitle(item.Object.Nickname)
                                    .SetSnippet(item.Object.Comment)
                                    .SetIcon(Util.GetBitmapDescriptor(Resources.GetIdentifier(item.Object.Tech + "_original", "drawable", Context.PackageName), Context)));
```